How to provide multiple query-params in micronaut http-client
I am calling an external api from my kotlin micronaut application using micronaut-http-client. The external-api requires multiple query-params, so I defined my interface like below:
@Client("query-classifier")
@Retryable(
    attempts = "\${micronaut.http.services.query-classifier.retry.attempts:2}",
    delay = "\${micronaut.http.services.query-classifier.retry.delay:10ms}",
    multiplier = "\${micronaut.http.services.query-classifier.retry.multiplier:2.0}",
    includes = [HttpClientException::class, HttpClientResponseException::class],
)
interface ClassifierClient {

    @Get("/{classifierPath}/classify")
    @Suppress("LongParameterList")
    fun classifyQuery(
        @QueryValue("q") query: String,
        @QueryValue("n") numberOfCategories: Int,
        @QueryValue("lf") lexicalFactor: Double,
        @QueryValue("tf") trainFactor: Double,
        @QueryValue("ls_cutoff") lexicalScoreCutoff: Double,
        @QueryValue("ts_cutoff") trainScoreCutoff: Double,
        @QueryValue("use_lexical_weighting") useLexicalWeighting: Int,
    ): CompletableFuture<ClassifierResponse>
}

and then I call this as below:
classifyQuery(          
                  query = query,
                  numberOfCategories = numberOfCategories,
                  lexicalFactor = lexicalFactor,
                  trainFactor = trainFactor,
                  lexicalScoreCutoff = lexicalScoreCutoff,
                  trainScoreCutoff = trainScoreCutoff,
                  useLexicalWeighting = useLexicalWeighting,
             ).await()

Although it is working fine, as per kotlin convention, I am surpassing method parameters count threshold of 6, hence I suppressed it in the above code. But in the long-run, I am trying to figure-out if I can pass these query-params as a map. Any help is appreciated!
